# How to extract 2D array from 4D array based on first and last indices

Tags: python, numpy

I currently have a numpy array of shape `(3, 890, 1100, 2)`. I would like to extract the 2d array that is at position `(0, 0-890, 0-1100, 0)`, so I would be left with the `890x1100` 2d array of the values when indices `1` and `4` are `0`.

In other words, I would like to access the array as if the parameters were in the order `(3, 2, 890, 1100)` and do something like:

```
 newArray = array[0][0]
```

I understand that I can do this with loops, but was wondering if there is a more "python-esque" way to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is a more pythonic way of indexing numpy arrays. Have a look at the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html) for details.

In your particular case, you can achieve the desired result as follows.

```
# Generate some data
data = np.random.normal(size=(3, 890, 1100, 2))
# Slice the data
subset = data[0, :, :, 0]
```

The `:` denotes "all elements along this axis".

Answer (score 1):

If you you want to access your data with `NewArray[0][0]`, you can also rearrange the axis with `NewArray=np.rollaxis(OriginalArray,-1)`

Then

```
>>> NewArray.shape
(2,3,890,1100)
```